# How Do I expose CFPropertyList for IPhone application from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, iphone, codeigniter

Is there any possibility to expose CFPropertyList for IPhone application from CodeIgniter  website.
I googled the examples and tutorials but I did not find any relevant information.

Simply I want to do the following.

1. I will call a URL from my Iphone application of the Codeigniter website by passing some query strings
2. and my php page will fetch the data from my MySql database.
3. finally it    would echo the result in Plist for Iphone application

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

> The PHP implementation of Apple's
>   PropertyList can handle XML
>   PropertyLists as well as binary
>   PropertyLists. It offers functionality
>   to easily convert data between worlds,
>   e.g. recalculating timestamps from
>   unix epoch to apple epoch and vice
>   versa. A feature to automagically
>   create (guess) the plist structure
>   from a normal PHP data structure will
>   help you dump your data to plist in no
>   time.

https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList

**I Haven't actually used this.**

Comment: Thanks Johan, actually I checked this library but I dont have how to integrate this with codeigniter,could you please direct me to some sample links.

Comment: To integrate with Codeigniter you could simply put it in the library folder as you would any library and load it with the vanilla php include or require statements. With the Path ( APPPATH . 'libraries/CFPropertyList/CFPropertyList.php' ) and then user it just like the examples @ https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList/tree/master/examples. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I use CFPropertyList all the time in my CI apps. The trick is to not use the CI library load method.It will always throw an error because CodeIgniter does not yet support Namespaces (likely why so many people are moving to Laravel), and the CFPropertyList library uses Namespaces.

Here is a example showing how to use CFPropertyList within a CI function:

```
public function getRecord($id){

    require_once(__DIR__.'/../libraries/CFPropertyList/CFPropertyList.php');

    $plistfile = ASSET_ROOT . 'uploads/fashion/FasionItems.plist';
    $content = file_get_contents($plistfile);

    /* notice use of the \ character */
    $plist = new CFPropertyList\CFPropertyList();

    $plist->parse($content);
    $plistarray = $plist->toArray();


    foreach($plistarray['Episodes'] AS $key => $record){

        if($record['ItemId'] == $id){  

            return $record;
            break;

        }

    }

    return FALSE;

}
```